# Additive-Group-Homomorphisms from a Local Field to the Non-zero complex numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis, local-field

I'm quite familiar with the $p$-adic numbers and $p$-adic analysis, so I already know that any continuous group homomorphism $\varpi_{p}:\left(\mathbb{Q}_{p},+\right)\rightarrow\left(\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} ,\times\right)$ is of the form: $$\varpi_{p}\left(\mathfrak{y}\right)=e^{2\pi i\left\{ \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{y}\right\} _{p}},\textrm{ }\forall\mathfrak{y}\in\mathbb{Q}_{p}$$ for some $\mathfrak{s}\in\mathbb{Q}_{p}$, where $\left\{ \cdot\right\} _{p}$ is the $p$-adic fractional part.

Now, let $\Bbbk$ be a number field, and let $\mathfrak{p}\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ be an irrational uniformizer of a prime ideal of $\Bbbk$. Let: $$d_{\mathfrak{p}}\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\left|\prod_{\sigma\in\textrm{Gal}\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\mathfrak{p}\right)/\mathbb{Q}\right)}\sigma\left(\mathfrak{p}\right)\right|$$ be the absolute value of the norm of $\mathfrak{p}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$— the smallest positive $\mathbb{Z}$-integer which is divisible by $\mathfrak{p}$. Then, letting $\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$ denote the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic completion of $\Bbbk$ (a local field) my guess is that every group homomorphism $\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}}:\left(\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}},+\right)\rightarrow\left(\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} ,\times\right)$ is of the form: $$\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}}\left(\mathfrak{y}\right)=e^{2\pi i\left\{ \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{y}\right\} _{d_{\mathfrak{p}}}},\textrm{ }\forall\mathfrak{y}\in\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$$ for some $d_{\mathfrak{p}}$-adic rational number $\mathfrak{s}$, where $\left\{ \cdot\right\} _{d_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ is the $d_{\mathfrak{p}}$-adic fractional part. However, letting $s\in\mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary, isn't $\mathfrak{y}\mapsto e^{2\pi is\left\{ \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{y}\right\} _{d_{\mathfrak{p}}}}$ then another such homomorphism? Or does there exist an $\mathfrak{s}^{\prime}\in\mathbb{Q}_{d_{\mathfrak{p}}}$ so that $\mathfrak{y}\mapsto e^{2\pi is\left\{ \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{y}\right\} _{d_{\mathfrak{p}}}}$ is the same as $\mathfrak{y}\mapsto e^{2\pi i\left\{ \mathfrak{s}^{\prime}\mathfrak{y}\right\} _{d_{\mathfrak{p}}}}?$ Or, am I on the wrong track, and I should actually be writing: $$\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}}\left(\mathfrak{y}\right)=e^{2\pi i\left\{ \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{y}\right\} _{\mathfrak{p}}}$$ for some $\mathfrak{s}\in\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Basically: given a number field $\Bbbk$, and a completion $\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$ at a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in the ring of $\Bbbk$-integers, let $\tilde{\Bbbk}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ denote the group of all continuous group homomorphisms $\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}}:\left(\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}},+\right)\rightarrow\left(\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} ,\times\right)$ (a sort of generalized Pontryagin dual of $\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$). What is $\tilde{\Bbbk}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ topological-group-isomorphic to (ex: does $\tilde{\Bbbk}_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$)? And, what is the general explicit formula $f\left(x,y\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\left\langle x,y\right\rangle$  for the duality bracket, so that every element of $\tilde{\Bbbk}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is of the form: $$\mathfrak{y}\mapsto\left\langle \mathfrak{s},\mathfrak{y}\right\rangle ,\textrm{ }\forall\mathfrak{y}\in\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$$ for some $\mathfrak{s}\in\tilde{\Bbbk}_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Comment: First, just because you can typeset in fraktur doesn't mean you should; this question is close to unreadable. Second, you need to add the word "continuous" in the second line of the question. One consequence of continuity is that (exercise) the image of any element is a p-power root of unity, so you can't go adding random complex numbers $s$ to the exponent.

Comment: Second, if $K/\mathbf{Q}_p$ is a finite extension, then, as topological groups, $K = \mathbf{Q}^d_p$ where $d = [K:\mathbf{Q}_p]$, so you can just choose a basis and reduce to the previous case. Or, if you want to write it more compactly, you can also write the general map as:

$$\psi(x) = \displaystyle{e^{2 \pi i \{ \mathrm{Tr}_{K/\mathbf{Q}_p}(s x)\}_p}}, \ x \in K
$$

where $s \in K$ is fixed, and $\{ \cdot \}_p$ is the $p$-adic fractional part.

Comment: 1) I write elements of non-Archimedean rings/fields using fraktur, so as to distinguish them from elements of Archimedean spaces. The meaning of notation should be independent of the context in which it occurs.

2) By $p$, do you mean a prime $\mathbb{Z}$-integer $p$, or my $\mathfrak{p}$?

3) By $K$, do you mean my $\Bbbk$, or my $\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Comment: 1) This is ridiculous, 2,3) I wrote what I meant; $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ and hence local, $p$ is a prime in $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Can you please answer the question using the terminology in which it was stated? This subject is not my forté; I do not understand how to translate your answer into my terminology.

Comment: You are asking about maps from $\mathbb{k}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Here $\mathbb{k}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a local field which I am denoting by $K$. I wrote down a formula describing all maps from $K$ ($=\mathbb{k}_{\mathfrak{p}}$) to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, which is what I understood your question to be. What else would you like me to clarify?

Comment: So, is your answer the statement: "Every continuous group homomorphism $\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}}:\left(\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}},+\right)\rightarrow\left(\mathbb{C}^{\times},\times\right)$ is of the form: $$\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}}\left(\mathfrak{y}\right)=e^{2\pi i\left\{ \textrm{Tr}_{\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathbb{Q}_{\mathfrak{p}}}\left(\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{y}\right)\right\} _{\mathfrak{p}}},\forall\mathfrak{y}\in\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$$ for some unique $\mathfrak{s}\in\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$"?

If so, thank you for answering my question! :D

Comment: I cannot make sense of what you mean by $\{ \cdot \}_{\mathfrak{p}}$. If you just mean $\{ \cdot \}_p$, then yes.

Comment: Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a uniformizer of a prime ideal in the ring of $\Bbbk$-integers. Then, every element of the local field $\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$ can be written as a Laurent series $\sum_{n=-\nu}^{\infty}a_{n}\mathfrak{p}^{n}$ for some $\nu\in\mathbb{Z}$, where the $a_{n}$s are elements of the residue field of $\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Then, I define: $$\left\{ \sum_{n=-\nu}^{\infty}a_{n}\mathfrak{p}^{n}\right\} _{\mathfrak{p}}\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum_{n=-\nu}^{-1}a_{n}\mathfrak{p}^{n},\textrm{ }\forall\sum_{n=-\nu}^{\infty}a_{n}\mathfrak{p}^{n}\in\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}$$.

Comment: As the $a_n$s are not elements of the residue field, this definition doesn't make sense. Rather, you need to chose representatives for the $a_n$ inside the ring of integers. The reason why the first map on $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is well defined is that $\{ \cdot \}_p$ really gives a canonical homomorphism (in fact, isomorphism) from $\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p$ to $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]/\mathbf{Z}$, and the ambiguity in lifting this to an element of $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]$ is an integer which doesn't matter when one applies $\exp(2 \pi i \cdot)$. This is the entire point why the first construction works.

Comment: I really recommend trying to understand the basic case of $\mathbf{Q}_p$, since everything else in your answer and comments suggests that currently you do not.

Comment: This is just a terminological flub. I always think of the residue field as "modular arithmetic" on the ring of integers; ex: $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}=\left\{ 0,1,\ldots,p-1\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$. Same goes for the more general case, where I identify $\mathbb{\Bbbk}_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ with its representatives in $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbbk_{\mathfrak{p}}}$.

That being said, now that you and I both know what I mean when I write $\left\{ \cdot\right\} _{\mathfrak{p}}$, is my earlier summary of your answer correct?

Comment: More nonsense. The choice of representative is very non-canonical and you have to make sure the formula you write down does not depend on this choice. I'm done here, try reading some introductory books on local fields and thinking about this problem yourself.